# How to convert a boost::hana::tuple into a std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I have the following code where I want to convert a `boost::hana::tuple` into a `std::variant`

```
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename Tuple>
struct to_variant;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_variant<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts...>;
};

auto my_tuple = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<char>, hana::type_c<float>);

using my_variant = typename to_variant<my_tuple>::type;
```

But I always get the error message

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class Tuple> struct to_variant'
using my_variant = typename to_variant<my_tuple>::type;
```

I tried to replace `std::tuple` with `hana::tuple` with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest three corrections in your code (two are already addressed in the other answer):

- Use `decltype(my_tuple)` to pass a *type* into `to_variant`
- Inside `to_variant`, use `using type = std::variant<typename Ts::type...>` to extract the types out of the Hana `type_c`'s.
- Use a `hana::tuple` in the specialization, not a `std::tuple`. More in general, you could also use a template template parameter here.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename Tuple>
struct to_variant;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_variant<hana::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<typename Ts::type...>;
};

auto my_tuple = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<char>, hana::type_c<float>);

using my_variant = typename to_variant<decltype(my_tuple)>::type;
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_tuple` is an object, but not *type*. (And its type is not `std::tuple` but `boost::hana::tuple` which should be used for the specialization.)

I think you want

```
template <typename Tuple>
struct to_variant;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_variant<boost::hana::tuple<Ts...>>
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts...>;
};

auto my_tuple = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<char>, hana::type_c<float>);

using my_variant = typename to_variant<decltype(my_tuple)>::type;
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^        ^
```

Comment: hmm that was easy... but I have probably now `hana::type_c` types in my variant?

Comment: @davidhigh My setup is a little more complex, my tuple type comes from some type computations from hana, therefore I have to use `hana::type_c` I guess...

Answer (score 1):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), this is pretty short (as always):

```
template <typename T> using unwrap = typename T::type;

template <typename T>
using to_variant = mp_rename<mp_transform<unwrap, T>, std::variant>;
```

Where you would use this as `to_variant<decltype(my_tuple)>`.

Basically, we first unwrap all the types (this gets us from something like `hana::tuple<hana::type_impl<int>::_, hana::type_impl<char>::_, ...>` to just `hana::tuple<int, char, ...>`) and then we rename the top-level template from `hana::tuple` to `std::variant`.